# How to modify a Magento left side navigation

Tags: magento-1.7, layered-navigation, navigation

My magento site using an extension called "**codnitive**" for left column side navigation. It is coming as a list of links with active and inactive headings.
But I want a check box should appear before each of links.So should I modified the code of the extension ? Or will it create any problem ? Kindly suggest..Thanks.
The module present in : `app/code/community/Codnitive/Sidenav/Block/navigation.php`
The template present in : `app/design/frontend/mypackage/default/codnitive/sidenav/navigation.phtml`
current image is the top one and required in the bottom

[image: Current navigation]

[image: Required navigaition]

Comment: share me that url

Comment: Editing the theme or core file directly is not recommended, however you can override those files. Please add more info regarding file paths and codes for us to understand more.